# Encrypting the connection string in web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, connection-string

I am trying to encrypt the connectionStrings of the web.config file. So I tried to used the aspnet_regiis tool to encrypt and used the below Command

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PSOC"
```

When I opened the web.config it encrypted the connectionStrings section of the web.config file. In IIS I created the APPPOOL identity with custom account which is like svc-abc. And when I call the API it does return the result works perfectly.

But I am not sure if I will still need to create the RSA Encryption Key and Grant that with the read access. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If I am not wrong, your problem is non existant becase the encryption is done with the DPAPI key, which is specific to a machine (and the decryption is possible only on the same machine)

Comment: @Steve I am not having any problem. But I am confused with the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx article being giving application identity read access  to the RSA Key